# how to add several images in a listview after getting their names from the sqlite database

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, android-sqlite, baseadapter

i have an android application that use sqlite and after it fetch the data it must be displayed in a listview.

my question is how to display images?

can anyone help me ???

## this my code

**//but here it display the same image for the hall list how to display each image in its right place ??**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {


            ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            // flag1
            int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier("brazil_flag",
                    "drawable", context.getPackageName());

            imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get image from drawable according to their names in the sqlite database and then display it in list view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334833/how-to-get-image-from-drawable-according-to-their-names-in-the-sqlite-database-a)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in terms of MVC will help [MVC pattern in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android)

1. Create a Layout with ListView which holds Images in each element
2. Create an Adapter to read the images from Database
3. In the Activity, use the Adapter to fill Images in the ListView